# Understanding this MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I sort of understand how this works but need more help

original question:

Use a correlated subquery to return one row per customer, representing the customer’s oldest order (the one with the earliest date). Each row should include these 
three columns: email_address, order_id, and order_date.

My Answer:

```
select email_address, order_id, order_date
from customers as T natural join orders
where order_date = 
  (select min(order_date)
  from orders as S
  where T.customer_id = S.customer_id
)
```

These are the schema:

customers: customer_id, email_address, password, first_name, last_name

orders: order_id, customer_id, order_date, ship_amount

My understanding is, I natural join customers and orders first.  This gives me only the customers who actually have orders.  Then I enter the where.  I take the orders table, and select only tuples where customer_id matches the parent one (but this part seems redundant to me since the parent and subquery should have exactly the same customer_id's)

Then select the min(order_date) from those tuples, then check for parent order_date equal to that (the subquery returns only one tuple). This means that (with my understanding) I should have only one tuple in my result (since only one tuple will exactly match that order_date)

I don't understand how I result with 7 tuples (note, my answer is apparently correct)

Thanks for any help

Comment: I accept that the requirement was for a correlated subquery, but I wouldn't use a correlated subquery for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so along with the responses from everyone, I figured this would be helpful to understand the OP's question `I don't understand how having the subquery return a single tuple allows me to get more than one tuple in my final result.`

think of it like this... you have multiple orders on one date.

```
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|  id   |   order_date   | order_quantity |  email_address |
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|   1   |      5/16      |       5        |bill@win.ing    |
|   2   |      5/16      |       6        |jim@win.ing     |
|   3   |      5/16      |       6        |stinky@win.ing  |
|   4   |      5/12      |       1        |tom@win.ing     |
|   5   |      5/12      |       7        |jeremy@win.ing  |
|   6   |      5/12      |       3        |silly@win.ing   |
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

there are **three** orders on the most recent date.... so when you `SELECT` something like this.

```
select email_address, order_id, order_date
from customers as T natural join orders
where order_date = 
  (select min(order_date)
  from orders as S
  where T.customer_id = S.customer_id
)
```

What this is actually saying is this

```
SELECT 
    email_address, 
    order_id, 
    order_date
FROM customers AS T 
NATURAL JOIN orders
WHERE order_date = "5/16"
```

as you can see there are multiple records of the most recent date in the table at May 16th **one tuple** so all of those records matching it will be returned.

the result of the query with my sample data would look like this

```
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|  id   |   order_date   | order_quantity |  email_address |
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|   1   |      5/16      |       5        |bill@win.ing    |
|   2   |      5/16      |       6        |jim@win.ing     |
|   3   |      5/16      |       6        |stinky@win.ing  |
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

**KEY NOTE:** **all of the records on that specific date will be returned**

hope that helps clarify :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a break down of what is happening.

These are the columns of data you wish to get:
    select email_address, order_id, order_date

selecting data from the customers table:
   from customers as T

matching only customers who have made an order:
   natural join orders

the above could have been better represented like this:
   inner join orders as O ON O.customer_id = T.customer_id

this is saying to get orders matching a specific date, in this case their first order, if they made multiple orders on the same date they would show up more than once.
    where order_date = 
    (select min(order_date)
        from orders as S
        where T.customer_id = S.customer_id
    )

if you want to eliminate the duplicates you can do so by doing either of the following:

(1) adding the keyword "DISTINCT" without quotes after select.

```
select DISTINCT email_address, order_id, order_date
from customers as T natural join orders
where order_date = 
  (select min(order_date)
  from orders as S
  where T.customer_id = S.customer_id
)
```

OR

(2) by adding a GROUP BY clause after the WHERE clause

```
select email_address, order_id, order_date
from customers as T natural join orders
where order_date = 
  (select min(order_date)
  from orders as S
  where T.customer_id = S.customer_id
)
GROUP BY email_address, order_id, order_date
```

However you will likely find that you are getting multiple customer_id with multiple order_id, and that would be because they have the same order_date.

You might be able to rewrite the query like the following, assuming your order_id are sequential.

```
select email_address, order_id, order_date
from customers as T natural join orders
where order_id = 
  (select min(order_id)
  from orders as S
  where T.customer_id = S.customer_id
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is...my solution had no duplicates and was apparently correct.  My problem is that I don't understand how having the subquery return a single tuple allows me to get more than one tuple in my final result.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way of writing it would be a bit simpler to understand and achieve the same result with less redundancy, the key being the `group by` clause.

```
select T.email_address, S.order_id, S.order_date
from customers as T 
inner join orders as S
on T.customer_id = S.customer_id
where S.order_date = (select min(S.order_date))
group by T.customer_id
```

Formatted for sakila sample schema:

```
select T.email, S.rental_id, S.rental_date
from customer as T 
inner join rental as S
on T.customer_id = S.customer_id
where S.rental_date = (select min(S.rental_date))
group by T.customer_id
```

Result set:

```
'MARY.SMITH@sakilacustomer.org', '76', '2005-05-25 11:30:37'
'PATRICIA.JOHNSON@sakilacustomer.org', '320', '2005-05-27 00:09:24'
[...]
599 row(s) returned
```

Comment: I had to use a correlation (homework assignment)  using a group by would have made it way way easier  :(

Comment: Ah, makes sense. To your point about multiple results, there is no aggregate function in your primary query, hence will return every match where your subquery is true. If you had `min(S.order_date)` in your first select statement then you would only get one result, assuming no `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
select cust.email_address, o.order_id, o.order_date
from customers cust
join orders o
on cust.customer_id = o.customer_id
where order_date = 
  (select min(order_date)
  from orders o
  where cust.customer_id = o.customer_id
)
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.